# Two TableViews in one View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, delegates, uitableview

I have one button and two `tableViewControllers` in one view controller. So, if i will press that button 1st table view controller will appear and it will display some data in rows. If i will select any row in that 1st table view controller, the 2nd table view controller will appear and it will need to display the corresponding data of selected row of 1st table view controller.  Here we have to use same table view delegate methods for 2 table view controllers at a time in one view controller.  Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use UINavigationController?

Comment: Did you mean table view rather than table view controller? Otherwise, how is ont controller in another controller? You would segue from one controller to another. Or you would use the same controller to control more than one table view. Did I misread something?

Comment: You say that you tap a button and then the `table view controller will appear`, and when you select a cell in the first table view `the 2nd table view controller will appear`. Does this mean that the two table view's are not being displayed at the same time? Or, both table views are available at any given time?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. Since the data source and delegate methods provide a reference to the tableview, you can simply check if it is equal to the first or the second table you have.

Example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if ([tableView isEqual:_firstTable]) {
    // Do something
  }

  else { // tableView == _secondTable
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest this also, or you could have the second table as an embedded view controller view from a second view controller.

Comment: or you can add a tag to the view in the nib file in the attributes editor. Then check for the tag as above. e.g if tableview.tag == 1 ? (something) : (other stuff)