# UITableView not displaying when embedded in another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create a view with three big subviews side-by-side. The three subviews should all be UITableViews packaged in UINAvigationControllers. I am using a subclass for UITableViewController named "TOGViewController" here.

When I do set this up, the UITableViews are not updating. The header (from the UINAvigationController) appears, but the space below stays white. When I debug it, I can see that cellForRowAtIndexPath is NEVER called. numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfRowsInSection and even heightForRowAtIndexPath are all called. But cellForRowAtIndexPath never!

CODE (only for the first, leftmost subview)

```
    // Create a big scrollview 3 times as wide as the screen and paginate it
    CGRect screenRect = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect wholeViewRect =screenRect;
    wholeViewRect.size.height= screenRect.size.height;
    wholeViewRect.size.width= screenRect.size.width * 3.0;
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: wholeViewRect];

    scrollView.contentSize = wholeViewRect.size;
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(screenRect.size.width, 0);
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = TRUE;

    self.view = scrollView;


    // Add a view to the left
    CGRect firstRect = screenRect;
    firstRect.size.width -= 1;

    TOGViewController *insightsViewController = [[TOGViewController alloc] init];
    insightsViewController.view.frame = firstRect;

    [self addChildViewController:insightsViewController];
    [scrollView addSubview: insightsViewController.view];
```

When I am using exactly the same TOGViewController (subclass of UITableViewController) and place this directly on the screen it works fine. But as soon as I embed this into a scrollview with two other UITableViews, none of the table views displays anything.

EDIT: I pasted the wrong code in the question from an older version. There are no UINavigationController around each UITableViewController. There is only one UINavigationController for the whole triple view consisting of 3 table views.

Comment: Is this an iPad application? or targeted at iPhone? I don't understand why you're putting a UINavigationController inside a scroll view. Can't you simply use a single navigation controller?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you want multiple UITableViews in one view, each with their own Navigation Controller, you'll want to put each TableView in its own Container View.</strike>

Check Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) and various [tutorials](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/working-with-custom-container-view-controllers/) available online.

There are [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836017/two-tableviews-in-one-view-controller) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649412/2-table-views-in-one-view) questions that deal with this topic. The key is to make each UITableView a property of your View:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView* firstTableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView* secondTableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView* thirdTableView;
```

You would only keep one delegate and datasource for all of them. Then in your UITableView delegate and datasource methods you would include if statements to check which UITableView you are in. 
For example:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

...

    if (tableView == self.firstTableView) {
        ...
    } else if (tableView == self.secondTableView) {
        ...
    } else {
        //thirdTableView code
    }
}
```

Comment: I pasted the wrong code in the question from an older version. There are no UINavigationController around each UITableViewController. There is only one UINavigationController for the whole triple view consisting of 3 table views. So its actually just three UITableViews (each with their own controller) side by side.

Comment: @MarkusBreuer I updated the question with this new information in mind.

Comment: Thank's for the help. Unfortunately, I don't think that this fixes the issue - actually I tried and it did change nothing. What you suggested is a different way to supply data to the TableViews. Using just one controller instead of three. At least thats what I got.

Comment: My problem, though, is, that the TableViews are just not displayed and the framework does not even call cellForRowAtIndexPath. This happens, when I only use ONE TableView inside an enclosing UIView. Somehow the enclosing view seems to kill the screen update - only with UITableViews. If I use three other UIView subclasses it all works fine. There content is displayed, no matter if they are enclosed in an outer container or not. Only the UITableView does not work.

Comment: I guess I just don't really understand what you are trying to do. I might be able to help more if you post your code attempting to make one UITableView work.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to display three Table Views side by side so you can switch between them easily with a (paged) horizontal scroll, @CocoaDog. In addition to this "triple view", I have a few other views, which are controlled by a UITabBar.

When I add one UITableViewController (packaged in an UINavigationController) to the UITabBar, everything works fine.

If I create a UIViewController with a Scroll View and add the same UITableView´Controller to the Scroll View and finally add that to the UINavigationController, the UITableView is NEVER drawn.

Thats the issue. The code is already up

Comment: In addition, the issue only comes up with an UITableView. I can embed every other kind of view (UIImageView, views with UILabels etc.) into the scroll view without problems. They behave the same if I add them to the UITabBar directly or embed them into a Scroll View. It is only the UITableView, which stops working when I embed it.

Comment: @MarkusBreuer UITableView is dramatically different from UIImageViews and UILabels. There are delegate and data source properties you must set up, and various methods you need to include. I also need to see your CODE. Not some snippet of code, not your explanation, but what you have in your .h and .m files.

Comment: I guess it makes sense to delete this question and set up a new one. On the other hand: please forgive me, but I am quite aware of the needs of a UITableView and did set up all the necessary delegates, data sources and implemented the mandatory methods. 

This Table View works fine ... as long as it is NOT embedded into another view. The issue is obviously not with the setup of the Table View. I must be making something wrong with integrating it into the view hierarchy, which leads to it not being drawn at all. Not even the background color of the Table View is visible on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is messed up with UITableViewDataSource Protocol delegate property on your TableViews. `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called on the tableView.datasource object. Although I am kinda confused as how `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is getting called but NOT `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Yes, @race_carr And not only tableView:numberOfRowsInSection is called. tableView: heightForRowAtIndexPath is called, too - exactly once for each item in the DataSource. But  tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: isn't!