# Two tableviews in one viewcontroller deleting cells

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

I am making an app with two TableViews in the same ViewController and need to be able to delete individual cells from each, but they are deleting cells from each other. How can I turn this into an if else statement or separate the two TableViews in any other way?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
    {

            colleges.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableViewOutlet.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: Use the `tableView` parameter to differentiate which table is calling the data source or delegate method. You will need to do this for all of the data source and delegate methods.

Comment: A different approach that may help you in the long run would be to use different classes for each tableview's datasource & delegate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two TableViews in one View Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836017/two-tableviews-in-one-view-controller)

Comment: You need to use tagging property to differentiate tableViews.